# Google analytic issue in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, google-analytics

If I put this code in Wordpress Footer.php the Google analytic code is visible in Footer when viewed in Browser inspect -

```
<?php if(of_get_option('google_analytics')):?><script><?php echo of_get_option('google_analytics'); ?></script><?php endif;?>
```

But when I put the same code in wordpress `<head></head>` in header.php

Then google analytic code is not visible in head in Browser inspect whats the issue?

Comment: of_get_option isn't a WordPress function. If this is from a plugin please add that info to the question.

Comment: Is this http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/ ?